# Importing a JSON data file into Tableau

Tags: json, parse-platform, tableau-api

I'm a parse.com novice.  I had an iPhone app built that sent to and stored data with `parse(core)`. The variables it stored were image, latitude, longitude, time,and type. It stored the information like a spreadsheet - each image was associated with a latitude, longitude, time and type. I wanted to use Tableau to take this data and create a visual representation, but I can't figure out how to import the data into Tableau.  When I export the parse file as a JSON file, it seems to be in string format, and Tableau does not recognize it as a table.  Is there a way I can export the parse data so tableau can easily recognize it as a data table?

Comment: The variables are stored as spreadsheet , you can use that only. Tableau will not be able to parse JSON as you think . Tabular data will do.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this can be best handled by writing some Tableau Extract API to convert your data to Tableau TDEs. If you want to schedule such refresh, you can use "addtoFile" tabcmd to add these TDEs to the existing dashboards.

Currently Tableau does not support out of box JSON support. Here is the latest discussion in the Tableau ideas forum.
[Here](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/1276)

Also i will recommend looking at the latest Web Data Connector. They will be very handy for lot of use cases.

Comment: Let me know if you need any specific help!

Answer (score 1):

Tableau does not read JSON data natively. By using Apache Drill, you can use Tableau to point at JSON data and start analyzing it.
[Here](https://datatoffee.com/2015/07/14/how-to-read-json-data-into-tableau-using-a-free-and-open-source-framework-apache-drill-on-windows/) is the link for complete explanation.